# Set-ADObject error in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I created a script to copy an existing user when a new one starts.

I went on leave for 2 weeks, come back and its not working - and no-ones touched the script

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(UserPrincipalName=copy_me@test.com)" -Properties Description, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, StreetAddress, PostOfficeBox, State, st, l, PostalCode, co, c, Pager, Department, Company, Manager, MemberOf | ForEach-Object {Set-ADObject -Identity "CN=New User,OU=Our-Users,DC=Test,DC=Com" -Replace @{Description="$($_.Description)";physicalDeliveryOfficeName="$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)"; StreetAddress="$($_.StreetAddress)"; PostOfficeBox="$($_.PostOfficeBox)"; st="$($_.st)"; l="$($_.l)"; PostalCode="$($_.PostalCode)"; co="$($_.co)"; c="$($_.c)"; Pager="$($_.Pager)"; Department="$($_.Department)"; Company="$($_.Company)"; Manager="$($_.Manager)"; OtherTelephone=" 8823"}}
```

The error powershell shows is:

```
    Set-ADObject : replace
At C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\user-process\copy-user.ps1:2 char:271
+ Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(UserPrincipalName=copy_me@test.com)"
 -Properties Description, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, StreetAddress, PostOffice
Box, State, st, l, PostalCode, co, c, Pager, Department, Company, Manager, Memb
erOf | ForEach-Object {Set-ADObject <<<<  -Identity "cn=New User,ou=our-users,dc=test,dc=com" -Replace @{Description="$($_.D
escription)";physicalDeliveryOfficeName="$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)"; Str
eetAddress="$($_.StreetAddress)"; PostOfficeBox="$($_.PostOfficeBox)"; st="$($_
.st)"; l="$($_.l)"; PostalCode="$($_.PostalCode)"; co="$($_.co)"; c="$($_.c)";
Pager="$($_.Pager)"; Department="$($_.Department)"; Company="$($_.Company)"; Ma
nager="$($_.Manager)"; OtherTelephone=" 8823"}}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (cn=Test User...,dc=test,d
   c=com:ADObject) [Set-ADObject], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : replace,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Com
   mands.SetADObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted error seems ambiguous:

```
 ForEach-Object {Set-ADObject <<<<  -Identity "cn=New User,
```

is displayed as the script line error, and agrees with the posted script, but the error message itself is showing:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (cn=Test User...,
```

Where is it getting "Test User" from?

Comment: helpdesk run a batch file that collects info such as the new users name, username, and who to copy.  This batch writes the get-aduser to a ps1 file, which is executed by scheduled task on my pc (as I have permissions and powershell)

Comment: InavlidOperation should read "(cn= New User...," - I went and removed the users actual name from the error.  Clearly shouldn't get interrupted half way through!

Comment: It's complaining about not being able to find that account.

Comment: If I use a user that doesn't exist, I get ObjectNotFound: (cn=... but when its a user that does exist, InvalidOperation: (cn=...

Comment: That's going to be hard to diagnose blind.  Any chance you're gotten connected to a RODC?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the user I was copying didn't have a street address entered.

After I put the existing users street address in, the command completed, and the user data was copied.

Thanks  mjolinor for your input :)